# How to use @HEAD in jax-rs using Jersey API or any other jax-rs API?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

How to use @HEAD in jax-rs using Jersey API or any other jax-rs API ? please give me sample.

Comment: here's one https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some dirt simple code illustrating how to send a HEAD request using the Jersey client:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);

WebResource resource = client
        .resource("http://localhost:8080/services/echo?message=Hello+World");

ClientResponse response = resource.accept(
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).head();
System.out.println(response);
```

Note the use of the `head` method. The `response` object returned contains lots of useful information, like the content type produced, the status code of the request, etc etc. The example can be translated to other client library types, but basically you send exactly the same request as you would with a GET, but with the HEAD method instead. Heres an example of the request that would be sent via a browser tool like ['REST Console'](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en):

#### Request

```
HEAD /services/echo?message=Hello+World HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: JSESSIONID=vWu5N2H8Y+P9SuZKWxhpIdgP.undefined
```

#### Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 03 May 2013 05:42:20 GMT
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but under jax-rs we can see a annotation as @HEAD .. so how this is useful to us. ?

Comment: HEAD is an HTTP action that is used mainly by proxy servers to determine wether to re-retrieve content (aka, to test wether content has changed on an origin server). It can also be used to test wether a site is up (aka, a kind of ping). In most cases you won't implement HEAD actions in your JAX-RS implementation, though by doing so you do (theoretically) improve its inter-operation with proxies.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and description now I got the idea.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to explicitly support HEAD as Jersey will automatically support it. Here is what Jersey's the documentation says:

> > By default the JAX-RS runtime will automatically support the methods HEAD and OPTIONS, if not explicitly implemented. For HEAD the runtime will invoke the implemented GET method (if present) and ignore the response entity (if set). For OPTIONS the Allow response header will be set to the set of HTTP methods support by the resource. In addition Jersey will return a WADL document describing the resource.

(Source: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2157)

Comment: the link is no longer valid

Comment: Thanks. This answer is probably what most people who arrive at this question (which is the first google result for `jersey HEAD request handling`) are looking for, and that's reflected in the votes. @user2241925, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: But, my `POST` API  supports only `OPTIONS`, but not `HEAD`. Why that? Should I implement it explicitly?